# Add register option on virtuemart Checkout

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have a site and I use Virtuemart on it. When user goes to checkout, there is a login form (I am already a member), but there is no any register option or button. How can I add the registration option on the checkout page? 
The form is above the billing and shipping adress information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The url is

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=registration
```

but you may want to create a menu item (in a hidden menu) pointing to it in order to get a proper SEF url.

Then you just insert a link in your code (template override of the login module would be the easiest, just lookup "Joomla template override" here on StackOverflow.

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer. The url is ok. I found it. But on which file should I do an override? And where should I add the registration link?

Answer (score 0):

YOUR_JOOMLA_FOLDER/components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/default.php